# Android Logcat: Why does logging come through in bursts?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I find LogCat a real nuisance no matter what device (or development tool) I use. There always seems to be a delay between when my programs do something and when logcat actually sees what my program did - sometimes up to 10-20 seconds or so.

Why is this? Is there a logcat buffering or flushing configuration that can be set either on the device or logcat itself to stop this from happpening?

I would like to see debug immediately - not seconds later. I have seen this problem using Eclipse, Android Studio and Logcat Rabbit. Xcode shows debug for iOS devices immediately. Surely Android devices should be capable of doing the same?

Comment: Presumably, there is something about your development machine that is causing the issue. This is not common behavior, and there are no configuration options that I am aware of that affect this. Do you experience this problem with an emulator? If not, try a different USB cable.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see the same behaviour on my Mac, PC, netbook with different USB cables and devices. I don't use the emulators because they are far too slow to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by another error. I have a flood of "Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API" errors being logged continuously into logcat and I was using a filter for my app. These floods of errors were causing delays in my debug appearing. Problem was solved by fixing the flood of errors.